# I try to install batocera on the internal hard drive from boot usb but it doesn't work

Tags: linux, usb, ssd, emulator, intel-atom

I have a mini PC with an Intel Atom processor (I'm not at home now, when I return I will edit the question adding the model), 2 Gb of RAM and a 30 Gb internal SSD.

I mounted the batocera image for atom processors with version 5.25 and it ran the operating system fine from the bootable USB.

The performance was very bad, since I tried the port of doom that comes with it and it was practically running at 2 fps, and I tried to install batocera from the internal options (as shown here: [Install Batocera from Batocera](https://wiki.batocera.org/install_batocera#install_batocera_from_batocera)) Connecting the mini PC to the network via cable, I selected the x86 architecture and the internal SSD as a place to install it and a message appeared that it was installed correctly, but when I turned on the mini PC, booting directly the SSD did not start Batocera, which "supposedly" is installed and an operating system called fedora appears.

Could it be due to a problem with the Batocera version, the USB speed (in the case of bad performance), problems when trying to install via network or that the SSD needs to be formatted?

EDIT: When I get home I will detail the processor and bios

Comment: *Batocera.linux is an open-source and completely free retro-gaming distribution that can be copied to a **USB stick** or an **SD card** with the aim of turning any computer/nano computer into a gaming console during a game or permanently. **Batocera.linux does not require any modification on your computer.***

Comment: @ChanganAuto but I want to install batocera on the mini pc not depend on a USB, and I follow the installation steps, the message appears that it was installed correctly but then there is nothing installed on it

Comment: The reason I copied that text in the home page was to hint that is the preferred method of running it. Yes, it can be installed internally but given the software it'll be running there's really not a great difference. But yes, it can be installed. Now, **how exactly have you installed it?** Please [edit] the question and describe how you did it, what boot options you changed in BIOS/UEFI and what happens when you try to boot.

Comment: @ChanganAuto What I mean by installation was that within batocera in the options there is a section that allows you to install batocera via the internet to a unit of your choice. And as for the fact that it doesn't make much difference if it is on USB or installed internally, yesterday I tried Doom by booting it from a 16 GB USB and the game was very very slow, 2 or 3 fps, is that because of the speed of the USB or the power of the computer?

Comment: It has little to nothing to do with the drive's speed. And when I asked you to [edit] the question was for you to describe what you actually did, not that you followed some instructions (we don't know how accurately you followed them and details matter), and, again, the other changes you made and, again, what exactly happens when you try to boot after the supposed installation.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I just edited the question, is my problem clearer now?

Comment: Yes, it's somehow clear but you are yet to inform about the changes you've made or haven't in the firmware in order to boot from the supposedly installed system. How old is your computer? If it's from ~2012 or newer then it has UEFI, not BIOS, and, according to the Batocera devs, Legacy/CSM/"BIOS" mode must be enabled.

Comment: @ChanganAuto The only thing I can contribute until I get home from work is that it is a mini PC with an Intel atom, it has bios with the option of UEFI Boot, and regarding booting the firmware I put the USB as a priority, and when I removed it and tested if Batocera was installed on the SSD, I put the Kingston SSD as priority and lastly I downloaded the iso from the Batocera website and with Balenaetcher I mounted the image on the USB.
When I get home I will add this complete information to the question